# Store list of Strings in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon AWS S3.
One of my applications processes 40000 updates an hour with a unique identifier for each update.
This identifier is basically a string.
At runtime, I want to store the ID in an S3 bucket for all updates.

But, as far as I understood, we need to store files in s3.

Is there anyway around this? 
Should I store a file.. Then read that file each time..append the name and store it again?

Any direction would be very helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

I want it to be stored like:

Id1

Id2

Id3
.
.
,
.

Edit: Thanks for the responses, I have added what is asked..

- I want to be able to just fetch all these IDs if and when a problem occurs in our system.
- I am open to using anything other than s3 as well. I was also looking into DynamoDB. With the ID as the primary key. But, these ID's might be repetitive in 1-2% cases.

Comment: Amazon Web Services S3 (Simple Storage Service) is indeed a service to store files (also called objects). You are correct, you can only store files on S3, and S3 doesn't care what's inside the files. But based on your description (which is not very clear), I think you need to use a database, especially if you want to get information (query) about these updates later, in a flexible manner.

Comment: I suggest you explain your problem a little bit further. Why S3 specifically. And what kind of operation you are going to do with your Ids

Comment: For us to advise how to _store_ data, it would be helpful if you could provide information about **how you intend to _use_ the stored data**. Could you please edit your question to include details of how the data will be **used**?

Comment: Hi. I have updated the question. Basically I will be fetching all the ID's whenever a problem occurs. So, that I know which ID's need to be re-processed in my application

Comment: @learning_to_write_good_code I still didn't get how IDs are not different. You fetch distinct IDs whenever a problem occurs, right, for reprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

In S3, you do not have concept of files and folders. All you have is a bucket and objects inside the bucket. However, the UI of AWS groups objects with **common prefixes** such that they **appear to be** in the same folder.

Also, there is nothing like appending to a file in S3. Since S3 has objects, what essentially happens is that the *so called append* deletes the previous object and creates a new object with the previous object's data appended with some more data.

So, one way to do what I think you're trying is :

Suppose you have all the IDs written at 10:00 in an S3 object called `data_corresponding_to_10_00_00`. For the next hour(and 40000 updates), if they have all new IDs, you can write them to another S3 object with the name `data_corresponding_to_11_00_00`.

However, if you do not want multiple entries in both the files, and you need to update the previous file itself, using S3 is not a great idea. Rather use a database indexed on ID so that the performance becomes faster.